# Multivriate Time Series Model - ARIMAX

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series

I have Weekly Units sales data of products for 2 years (104 weeks). And I am trying to **forecast** the Unit sales for each productid for next 8 weeks.. 
Please find the data image below.

[image]

**note:** Productid column denotes the products. Columns like Mtype, DType, Weight and PPU(Price Per Unit) are main KPIs helps in Unit's sales.
My Target Variable is Units,  All other columns are Predictor Variables.

Like the above 3 weeks data sample, I have data around 3000+, for 104 weeks. How can I perform multivariate time series analysis ?

I don't have any other period column other than "Week" column. How can I make it into ts data ?

I am stuck in the begining intself, as how to use the time (period) column ?

Comment: are you trying to relate units sold to price and to latent seasonal factors or level shifts or trends ?

Comment: Hi @IrishStat, I am trying the forecast the Units column. Which means, I am trying to forcast the No.of Units, that will be sold for next 8 weeks.

Comment: using price as a possible predictor . post data for one of your 3000 examples

Comment: @IrishStat Sorry, I couldn't understand your second part of the comment. Actually  myTarget variable is "Units", all others are predictor variables.  Even though, if I consider Price as Dependent Variable, what about the time column ? I am not sure how to use my "Weeks" column. It Doesn't have a year, or date. how can I use it ?

Comment: the others look like labels or classes (qualitative). you don't have to worry about time .. just make sure you have readings for every week.

Comment: Yes.I have continuously  for 104 weeks, for 50 unique product IDs.  I can iterate the product one by one. I am planning to use ARIMAX. Can you please guide me how to do without time variable ? I haven't done a single model without time or year column. Any links or materials would be helpful. I can learn that and write the code. Thanks in advance @IrishStat

Comment: actually post 1 example 104 rows two columns . time effects will be picked up since observations are made at fixed intervals of time.